# What kind of outlet should I use in my UPS?

Tags: ups

I have a Powercom Imperial Series UPS (625 VA) and I want to connect it to a PC and a monitor.

Which outlets should I prefer and why? Do you know the difference between battery backup and surge protected outlets?

Here are the outlets of my UPS.

[image]

Comment: Tell us more about your PC. Is it a low-end system? A gaming system? Or what? And tell us more about your monitor. Is it an LCD monitor? High end? Or what? Also, tell us what you are are expecting the UPS to do.

Comment: Low End system. LCD monitor. Priority number 1 : I don't want to lose any data and priority number 2 : I want to have time to turn it off when the breakout happens. I think the answer below fits me but share yours if you got something to add.

Comment: Then plug the PC and the monitor into the battery backup outlets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest difference between the surge protected and battery backup slots are, that when the power fails, the surge protected slots will not be battery powered.

All 5 slots will be protected against a lightning strike travelling inwards over the input, so your devices are protected against a static discharge.

Now to answer your question which one you should use for your pc and monitor.

Obviously the PC one would be used for the battery. The question is if you want to be able to use your pc during a power outage, or if you just settle for: Just keep it running, I'll start using it again when the power comes back.

If this is the case, connect the monitor to the surge protected outlet. If you want to keep using the pc, the monitor is crucial, so put that to the battery backup too. Do note, that it will drain the UPS battery quicker because now 2 devices are draining its battery.

For that reason, my recommendation would be to use the PC on battery, monitor on surge and not use the pc during an outage.

Comment: Thanks, and a newby side-question since you said it drains the batteries. Do they not get charged while there is no outage?

Comment: Hi @Lev - yes the batteries do charge during normal usage (when there is no outage).  They do this by drawing slightly more than your PC needs to use to run and storing the difference in the batteries for when the power does go out.

Comment: @Lev yes as Pointed out by Fazer87, but when there is a poweroutage, and the battery backup is activated, more devices hooked on it means that its battery will be drained more quickly. Depending on your UPS and system specs it can be that with just the PC you have 15 minutes of backup, and with the monitor attached, only 10 minutes.

Comment: @Lev: Note that connecting the monitor to a surge-only outlet requires that you install software that communicates with the UPS (often provided with it), that immediately shuts down or hibernates the computer when the power goes out; without the monitor, you can't close what you're working on and shut down gracefully. Unless you have a large UPS, they aren't intended to keep working, or even to keep the PC running until the power returns; they provide power long enough to close what you're doing & power down. It generally doesn't make sense to not have the monitor on a battery backup outlet.

Comment: @fixer1234 yeah I agree. I have both pc and monitor connected to the battery outlets.

Answer (score 1):

**Battery Backup Outlets** will supply Quality power to your equipment as well as run it on the batteries during a Brown out or black out. The outlets will also provide surge protection to what is plugged in.

**The Surge Protected outlets**. Will do what it say provide clean power when there is a surge or spike through the power lines in your home.

Depending on how much power your computer uses is how long it will stay on during a outage. Mostly will give you enough time to wrap things up and safely shutdown the computer.

One of my recommendations is have the pc hooked up to the Battery Backup outlets but have your computer shut down as soon as it gets on the power. And have your modem and router hooked up so you will still have online access for reasons during a storm. Because Power still flows through the Coaxial most of the time. Ive been through a few brown outs and have still been able to use the internet when the power was out on my mobile devices.

Answer (score -2):

> The Surge Protected outlets. Will do what it claims to provide clean power when there is a surge or spike through the power lines in your home.

And then we view specification numbers.  It will absorb maybe hundreds of joules.  Destructive surges can be hundreds of thousands of joules.  What happens when a near zero (UPS) protector tries to absorb a destructive surge?  Destruction of a UPS.

A surge is electricity.  That means when a surge current is incoming to a UPS, at the same time, that same current is also outgoing into any attached PC or monitor.  Where is this protection?

Advertising hypes subjective claims to a public that ignores spec numbers.  It says it is 'surge protection'.  Then it must 'absorb' or 'block' surges - to protect PC and monitor.  How does its near zero joules 'absorb' hundreds of thousands of joules?    It does not.  How does its 2 cm protector part 'block' what three miles of sky could not?  It does not.  It only claims to protect from a tiny surge that are already made irrelevant by more robust protection standard inside all electronics - including PC and monitor.

Either a surge is all but invited inside to hunt for earth ground destructively via appliances (and adjacent protectors sometimes make that damage easier).  Or a surge is connected harmlessly to earth BEFORE entering a building.  This 'whole house' solution is an only solution always found in facilities that cannot have surge damage.  This superior solution costs about $1 per protection appliances.  And is essential to even protect that UPS.

Then include numbers.  For example, lightning is typically 20,000 amps.  So a minimal and properly earthed 'whole house' protector is 50,000 amps.  Even direct lighting strikes do not damage the superior solution.  Then hundreds of thousands of joules harmlessly dissipate outside a house.  Then all appliances (dishwasher, furnace, bathroom GFCIs, recharging phone, clocks, refrigerator, air conditioner, etc) are protected.  If that PC needs protection, then everything needs protection.  Informed consumers earth one 'whole house' protector to actually have surge protection.

How to separate effective solutions from near zero solutions?  Every effective protector makes a low impedance (ie less than 10 feet) connection to single point earth ground.  Why does that UPS not even discuss earth ground?  Because it does not have that connection and does not claim to protect from surges that are typically destructive.  A protector is only as effective as its earth ground.

Demonstrated is a difference between recommendations based in knowledge and experience compared to others who only recite what is promoted by advertising.  Anyone can read those numbers.  Most recommend by ignoring even  the simplest numbers.

Comment: This appears to be commentary on NetworkKingPin's answer rather than an answer to the original question (probably why it attracted a downvote).  The Q&A format restricts answers to responses to the question.  You might want to consider asking a new question for which this is the answer and then self-answering with a cleaned-up version of this post (stick to the technical information and leave out the commentary).  The question could be something like, "Is a UPS's surge protection adequate against lightning?"

Comment: I don't care about any person.  The comment is 100% about the technology. Please read it as it is intended.  Most will only post what advertising promotes.  That says nothing about any person.  That says everything about why so many urban myths exist and what those myths are.  Entire post is only about one thing - surges, what they are, what urban myths promote, and what actually does provide protection from surges.  No person is attacked or even considered.  Urban myths are exposed and a solution, that has been well understood for over 100 years, is identified.  Please read as intended.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't what was asked in this question.  That's why it would be better to present the information in answer to a question that asks this.  SU is a Q&A site rather than a forum.  If someone is looking for the information in this answer, they won't be able to easily find it if it's buried as a response to a different question.  As soon as you hit 50 rep (perhaps from this posted appropriately?), you could post a comment on NetworkKingPin's answer about this point and link to your dedicated thread.

Comment: The question was about connecting to a UPS plug that claims surge protection.  No UPS claims effective surge protection.  In fact, near zero surge protection provided by a UPS is also found on other duplex wall receptacles connected from the same house circuit breaker.  I do not understand your confusion.  But all UPS plug recommendations were made assuming a UPS does effective surge protection.  No adjacent UPS does that.  Not one. Same near zero protection provided by a UPS exists on all receptacles - on that UPS an on other receptacles.  Matters little to none which receptacle is connected.